# Are coefficients of a sequence of vector in a space generated by a sequence, bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$ such that $b_n \to b_0$ and let $B=\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cup \{b_0\}$

Let $B$ linearly independent and $\forall b \in B: \left\| b \right\|> m$

Let $U=\operatorname{span}(B)$

Let $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of U such that $v_m \to b_1$

We have that 
$$
v_m=\sum_j a_{m,j}b_{m,j}
$$
with $a_{m,j} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b_{m,j} \in B$

My question is if $|a_{m,j}|$ is limited, that is $\exists M>0 : \forall m,j |a_{m,j}| < M$

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: If $V$ is Hilbert and $b_n$ is orthonormal, then yes, the coefficients $a_{m, j}$ are uniformly bounded. That's because $$ |a_{m,j}|^2\le \| v_m\|^2$$ and the sequence $v_m$ is bounded because it is convergent. The corresponding concept in a Banach space is that of [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis). But your case is too general to be true; see the answers you received.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro thanks but it's not a Hilbert space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

Take $V = (L^1[0,1],\|\cdot\|_1)$.

Let $B = \{1, 1+x, 1+x^2, \ldots\}\subseteq V$. Notice that $B$ is linearly independent, $\|b\|_1 \ge 1, \forall b \in B$, and we have $1+x^n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$ since:

$$\big\|(1+x^n) - 1\big\|_1 = \int_0^1 x^n \,dx =\frac{1}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

Also, $\mathrm{span}\,B$ is in fact $\mathcal{P}[0,1]$, the space of all polynomials on $[0,1]$.

Define a sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathrm{span}\,B$ as $$f_n(x) = 1 + x + (1-x)^n, \quad x \in [0,1]$$

We have $f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1+x$:

$$\big\|1 + x + (1-x)^n - (1+x)\big\|_1 = \int_0^1 (1-x)^n \,dx =\frac{1}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

However, we have:

$$1 + x + (1-x)^n = 1 + x + \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^kx^k$$

so for $n > 2$ the coefficient of the element $1+x^{n-1}$ in $f_n$ must be be $(-1)^{n-1}n$, since $1+x^{n-1}$ is the only element of $B$ with the power $x^{n-1}$.

Thus, the coefficients are unbounded.

Comment: thanks once again, I must find the solution to this problem, i'm driving crazy

Answer (score 2):

No, this is false. To see this, choose $j_m$ such that $\|b_{j_m}-b_0\| < 2^{-m}$ and put
$$
a_{m,j} :=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{for }j\notin\{0,j_m\}\\
2^{m/2} &\text{for }j = 0\\
-2^{m/2} &\text{for }j = j_m.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the $a_{m,j}$'s are definitely not bounded, but
$$
\|v_m\| = \left\|\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{m,j}b_j\right\| = \|a_{m,0}b_0 + a_{m,j_m}b_{j_m}\| = 2^{m/2}\|b_{j_m} - b_0\| < 2^{-m/2},
$$
which tends to zero. Hence $v_m\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: $v_m$ should converge to $b_1$, which cannot be $0$ since $B$ is linearly independent. You could add $b_1$ to your sequence $v_m$.

Comment: Ok. Since there were some mistakes in your post, I assumed this was another one. But yeah, add $a_{m,1} := 1$ for each $m$. Please upvote my answer, thanks.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but sure, I'll upvote it!

Comment: Lol, sorry. I just saw your nick above my answer without knowing there was another one. Therefore, I thought you were OP. I also think that OP just put $b_1$ as limit without remembering he/she used it before. Upvoted yours, too.

Comment: @amsmath thanks for your answer

Comment: You are welcome.